# iTextSharp Duplicating Acrofields

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, acrofields

I have an acroform on page 1 of my document. I am creating a blank second page and i would like to show one of the fields on this page as well. If the user changes the value of this field on either of the pages, i want them both to show the new value. I found a few posts that are showing this type of solution but it doesn't work as expected:

```
                    PdfFormField fNotes = PdfFormField.CreateTextField(writer, false, false, 500);
                string fieldNotes = "tfNotes";
                fNotes.FieldName = fieldNotes;
                PdfFormField widgetNotes = PdfFormField.CreateEmpty(writer);

                PdfPCell notesCell = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("test", helv8))
                {
                    BorderWidthLeft = 0,
                    BorderWidthRight = 0,
                    BorderWidthTop = 0,
                    BorderWidthBottom = .5f
                };
                TextField tField = new TextField(writer, new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100), fieldNotes);
                writer.AddAnnotation(fNotes);
                writer.AddAnnotation(widgetNotes);
```

In this example, the field on page 1 is named tfNotes. If i understand correctly, i need to create a second widget reference to the acrofield. I think the above code would be for a field that doesn't already exist, in my case it does. Is there an easier way to grab a field by name on page 1 and create a duplicate reference to it on page 2?

Thank you for your time!

EDIT:

This works as expected when i take the table out of the equation, but once i try to put the duplicated field into the PdfPCell it shows up on the page at 0,0 with a width and height of 0. For some reason the rectangle of the cell is returning as 0,0,0,0.

```
PdfPCell notesCell = new PdfPCell()
                {
                    BorderWidthLeft = 0,
                    BorderWidthRight = 0,
                    BorderWidthTop = 0,
                    BorderWidthBottom = .5f
                };
                //Notes Cell Rectangle
                float llxNotes = notesCell.GetLeft(0);
                float llyNotes = notesCell.GetBottom(0);
                float urxNotes = notesCell.GetRight(0);
                float uryNotes = notesCell.GetTop(0);

                //Notes Duplicate
                string fieldNotesName = "tfQuoteNotes";
                TextField tField = new TextField(writer, new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(llxNotes, llyNotes, urxNotes, uryNotes), fieldNotesName)
                {
                    FieldName = fieldNotesName
                };
                tField.SetRotationFromPage(doc.PageSize);
                writer.AddAnnotation(tField.GetTextField());
```

I think all i need to do now is find the correct rectangle coords for the cell.

Comment: In PDF if two fields of the same type have the same name, they will both update if one receives a value. Are you assigning the same name to both fields?

Comment: And if you have given them the same name "tfNotes" have you verified the PDF is being generated with those names as desired and they aren't being over written by the writer (i.e. page1_tfNotes, page2_tfNotes).

Comment: I am sure that the existing field is named tfNotes, but when i look at the second page there isn't anything there in the cell. If i look in RUPS, it is just an empty array on that page under Annots so i know something is going wrong here. It isn't actually creating the duplicate field.

Answer (score 0):

So the part i was missing was a CellEvent, which i don't completely understand why, but here is the final working snippet for anyone who needs it:

```
                    PdfPCell notesCell = new PdfPCell()
                {
                    BorderWidthLeft = 0,
                    BorderWidthRight = 0,
                    BorderWidthTop = 0,
                    BorderWidthBottom = .5f
                };

                //Notes Cell Rectangle
                float llxNotes = notesCell.GetLeft(0);
                float llyNotes = notesCell.GetBottom(0);
                float urxNotes = notesCell.GetRight(0);
                float uryNotes = notesCell.GetTop(0);

                //Notes Duplicate
                string fieldNotesName = "tfQuoteNotes";
                TextField tField = new TextField(writer, new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(llxNotes, llyNotes, urxNotes, uryNotes), fieldNotesName)
                {
                    FieldName = fieldNotesName
                };
                tField.SetRotationFromPage(doc.PageSize); //Needed since this page is rotated 90 from the first page

                iTextSharp.text.pdf.events.FieldPositioningEvents events = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.events.FieldPositioningEvents(writer, tField.GetTextField());
                writer.AddAnnotation(tField.GetTextField());
                notesCell.CellEvent = events; //This somehow ignores the original rectangle (0,0,0,0) in the TextField definition above and changes it to the cell's rectangle
```